# Installing 20.04.3 server (subiquity) without GRUB

Tags: server, uefi, subiquity

I’d like to install ubuntu-server 20.04.3 LTS but I already have a boot manager and don’t want to overwrite it.

I know ubiquity can be run with the `--no-bootloader` option, and there are hints subiquity used to support `--bootloader=none` but is there a current way to install only the server OS files and leave the EFI partition alone?

Comment: If you don't install a boot loader, you won't be able to boot the operating system.  I don't know why you'd want to have an operating system installed that can't be booted.  Normally installing the bootloader merges other operating systems.  It won't delete your other boot loaders, they'll still be in the EFI partition.

Comment: " but I already have a boot manager " and that bootmanager is what? You will need a linux compatible bootloader (and the windows one is not). If you have LILO you do not need grub.

Comment: I have rEFInd, and am installing on a T2 Mac. Subiquity always fails at the bootloader installation phase. Since Ubiquity can install without a bootloader, I can install the Desktop edition and then strip out all the GUI stuff, but I have nine more of these to do and it would be much easier if I could just turn off Subiquity’s bootloader phase.

Comment: I doubt the "live" server installer (`subiquity`) supports this use case.  You might be able to do it if you use the "legacy" server installer (which is based on `debian-installer`).  Suggestions in this thread might be helpful for you - https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=135262  .

Answer (score 0):

A good question, increasingly important since Canonical seem to be switching to Subiquity for the Desktop Installer too. So this is what I have found out.

In the current source of Subiquity at https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/main/subiquity/cmd/server.py there is a command line parameter of --bootloader that has the helptext of "Override style of bootloader to use" with possible values of 'none', 'bios', 'prep' or 'uefi'.

It is hard to follow the flow through the whole source, but it appears that setting this parameter overrides the default probing to work out what sort of bootloader to install. Then, when the server installation actually takes place,  if the bootloader attribute has the value Bootloader.NONE then the installation of a bootloader is skipped.

Comments in the source indicate that s390x installations do not install a bootloader.

As with Ubiquity on the desktop installation one may need to break out to the command line in order to invoke "subiquity --bootloader=none".

Unlike Ubiquity there does not appear to be a shorter "-b" option.